# Store post form values in hidden input array

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and here's my code for a number guessing game. Since I don't know how to define a random number, I chose the number myself, 80. I'm trying to store all the guesses prior to the right one, and after the right guess, print them out on the screen. But I can't seem to be able to get it right since it only prints only the last guess before the right one.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$allguesses = array();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $t = $_POST["guess"];
    $sayi = 80;

    if($sayi >$t){
        echo 'Guess higher';
    }elseif($sayi == $t){
        echo "You've guessed it right!<br>";
        echo 'Guessed numbers: <br>';
        foreach($_POST["tmn"] as $y){
            echo $y . ',';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Guess lower';
    }
    array_push($allguesses,$t);
}
?>
<form method="post">
Guess the number:
<input type="number" name="guess" min ="1" max = "100"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php 
foreach($allguesses as $x){
    echo "<input type ='hidden' name = 'tmn[]' value=' ".$x . " '>";
}
?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` or some serverside storage - database,file, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed uneeded codes.

Changed method of showing previous guesses with the below code.

```
echo implode( ", ", $_POST["tmn"] ); // cleaner
```

This block handles storing previous guesses into an array that is used for displaying previous guesses.

```
if( isset( $_POST ) ) {
        $_POST["tmn"][] = $t;
    }
```

Fixed previous version of below block of code so that hidden `<inputs>` of previous guesses are outputted properly..

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST["tmn"] ) ) {
        foreach($_POST["tmn"] as $x){
            echo "\n<input type ='hidden' name = 'tmn[]' value='$x'>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $t = $_POST["guess"];
    $sayi = 80;

    if($sayi >$t){
        echo 'Guess higher';
    }elseif($sayi == $t){
        echo "You've guessed it right!<br>";
        echo 'Guessed numbers: <br>';
        echo implode( ", ", $_POST["tmn"] );
    }else{
        echo 'Guess lower';
    }
    if( isset( $_POST ) ) {
        $_POST["tmn"][] = $t;
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
Guess the number:
<input type="number" name="guess" min ="1" max = "100"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST["tmn"] ) ) {
        foreach($_POST["tmn"] as $x){
            echo "\n<input type ='hidden' name = 'tmn[]' value='$x'>";
        }
    }
?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sessions seem the best for where you are in your learning curve.

The session allows the normal stateless http protocol to remember things between each submission of a form or forms. So we will save each guess in an array of guesses in the SESSION, which in PHP is an array as well.

```
<?php 
session_start();  // create a session, or reconnect to an existing one

if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["guess"]) ) {
    $_SESSION['guesses'][] = $_POST["guess"];   // keep an array of guesses

    // $t = $_POST["guess"]; no need for extra variables on the stack
    $sayi = 80;

    if($sayi > $_POST["guess"]){
        echo 'Guess higher';
    }elseif($sayi == $_POST["guess"]){
        echo "You've guessed it right!<br>";
        echo 'Guessed numbers: <br>';
        foreach($_SESSION['guesses'] as $guess){
            echo $guess . ',';
        }
        $_SESSION['guesses'] = array();  // clear the old guesses out
    }else{
        echo 'Guess lower';
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    Guess the number:
    <input type="number" name="guess" min ="1" max = "100"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For random numbers you can use [rand($min, $max)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rand.php). to store the guesses you can use the global variable `$_SESSION`.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        //start session (needed to use the $_SESSION variable)
        start_session();
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

            //if empty -> initalize array
            if (empty ($_SESSION['allguesses']){
                $_SESSION['allguesses'] = array ()
            }

            $t = $_POST["guess"];
            $sayi = 80;

            if($sayi >$t){
                echo 'Guess higher';
            }elseif($sayi == $t){
                echo "You've guessed it right!<br>";
                echo 'Guessed numbers: <br>';

                //echo all guesses from $_SESSION variable
                foreach($_SESSION['allguesses'] as $y){
                    echo $y . ',';
                }

            }else{
                echo 'Guess lower';
            }

            //push in $_SESSION variable
            array_push($_SESSION['allguesses'],$t);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            Guess the number:
            <input type="number" name="guess" min ="1" max = "100"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```